# Need help to create overlay like in the pic in android

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I need to make an overlay Just like this Attached Pic... Need help to make it... I need to mark a position just like in the pic with red....

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a new class extending Overlay.
- Use the constructor to pass it 4 GeoPoint in order to delimit your zone
- Override the `boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow, long when)` method :

  - Call `super(canvas, mapv, shadow)`
  - Create a path using your GeoPoints and the MapView projection : `mapv.getProjection().toPixels(geopoint, newPoint)`
  - Use `canvas.drawPath(path,paint)` to draw the path